# Call all the value from DB to dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, select

I have a material table where the all materials are being inserted in the desc column. desc values can be as many as possible.

sample:

```
desc
 poly canvass
 metal
 washer
 knot
```

Here's the code i did.

```
<?php 
$resource=mysql_query("Select * from material",$con);

while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
    { 

    ?>
<select>
<option value="<?php echo $result2[desc] ?>"><?php echo $result2[desc] ?></option>
</select>

</tr>
<?php };?>
```

But it generates four dropdown that corresponds each of the four values in my db
like:

```
dropdown1      dropdown2      dropdown3      dropdown4
polycanvass    metal          washer         knot
```

How can I make all of the values in the desc column to appear in one dropdown?

Comment: I see a use of `mysql_*`. Don't do it. It is a lie, put forward by the Russians, the Chinese, or any one else you're afraid of. Beware `mysql_*`, and place your undying faith in the hands of `PDO` and `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the select tag from the while loop and put it outside.

**I would recommend you to use mysqli instead of mysql**

**PHP MySQLi = PHP MySQL Improved!**

**Note:** The MySQLi extension is designed to work with MySQL version 4.1.13 or newer

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","dbname");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $resource= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM material");

    echo "<select>";
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($resource)){
        echo '<option value="'.$result[desc].'">'.$result[desc].'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php 
    $resource=mysql_query("Select * from material",$con);
    ?>
    <select>
    <?php
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $result2[desc] ?>"><?php echo $result2[desc] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    </select>
    ?>
```

select should be out of while loop because for each value it also gets repeated and you will end up having as many drop downs as the number of total records.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
    $resource=mysql_query("Select * from material",$con);
    ?>
    <select>
    <?php
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$result2[desc].'">'.$result2[desc].'</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
```

Select out of loop and shorter way to output `<option>`